# Angularjs: execute $timeout callback from controller and directive link in the right order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I have this simple app with a custom directive and it's controller:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('customDir', function($timeout){
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: 'custom dir template',
        controller: 'customDirCtrl',
        link: function () {
          $timeout(function(){
            console.log('link');
          });
        }
  }
})
.controller('customDirCtrl', function($timeout) {
    $timeout(function(){
            console.log('ctrl');
          }).then(function(){
    });
});
```

Both the directive's link function and controller contains a timeout callback which in the case above will be executed in this order: ctrl's function then link's function. See here: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/EoxgvV

What I need is to ensure that the timeout callback in the controller is executed after the one from the directive's link. How do I do that?

Comment: You apparently have XY problem. Why do you need that? Please, explain what's your case. Also, this can be handled with a controller alone; currently link function is obsolete in favour of $postLink controller hook.

Comment: @estus I have a window scroll event handler in the link which scrolls an inner div containing a vertical side menu and having bootstrap scrollspy on it to which add 'active class to the menu items. I want to override this class addition when user click a menu item, because when clicking one of the bottom items (but not the last one) in the menu, it always ends up with the last item to be marked as active because of scroll position. The click handler function is in controller and the scroll event handler in the link. To be short :)

Comment: Yes, this is XY problem. The necessity for such flimsy things as timeout order indicates that something went wrong. I'd suggest to re-ask the question with your real case and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The division between functions in controller and link doesn't make much sense. Methods can (or should) be defined on scope OR controller instance. As it was said, there's currently no need for link function, this can be handled in controller alone.

Answer (score 0):

The [initialization of the directive](http://ngninja.com/posts/angularjs-directive-life-cycle) is composed of these 4 events in the same order:

1. compile
2. controller
3. pre-link
4. post-link

So, you need to move that timeout to the `compile` function instead to get it executed prior to controller initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you have some event in directive, you can bind that element and on change, you can do timeout. If you have variable you can use $watch or if you have some other event you can use $on and $emit to emit that event to controller. It's not pretty solution, but it can work.

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast from the link when the timeout is done

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('customDir', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'custom dir template',
    controller: 'customDirCtrl',
    link: function ($scope) {
      $timeout(function(){
        console.log('link');
        $scope.$broadcast('linkTimeoutDone')            
      });
    }
 }
})
.controller('customDirCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('linkTimeoutDone', function() {
    console.log('ctrl');
  });
});
```